# Specific input for post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to create the PHP page that can retrieve data from database but for example when the user put 15 for age and selects the Categories "Male" then the data show for both male and female. How can I make it more specific just male for male, female for female Male & Child for Male & Child and so on? `

```
<?php
    // check if the form has been submitted and display the results
    if(isset($_POST["Age"]) && isset($_POST["Categories"])){
        define('DB_NAME', 'test');
        define('DB_USER', 'test');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'test');
        define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
        $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        if (!$conn){die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error());}
        // escape the post data to prevent injection attacks
        $Age = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Age']);
        $Categories = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['Categories']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Medic Rate` WHERE `Age` LIKE '%$Age%' AND `Categories` LIKE '%$Categories%'"; 
        $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        // check if the query returned a result
        if(!$result){echo 'There are no results for your search';}
        else{
            // result to output the table
            echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">'; 
            echo "<tr>
                <th>Medic_Id</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Categories</th>
                <th>Plan</th>
                <th>Rate</th>
            </tr>"; 
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                echo "<tr><td>"; 
                echo $row['Medic_Id'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $row['Age'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $row['Categories'];
                echo "</td><td>"; 
                echo $row['Plan'];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $row['Rate'];
                echo "</td></tr>";  
            }
            echo "</table>";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    } // end submitted
    else{// not submitted to output the form
?>
<form action=" " method="post">
    <label>Enter Age:</label>
    <input name="Age" type="number" placeholder="Type Here"><br><br>
    <label>Enter Categories:</label>
    <select name="Categories" />
        <option value="Male">Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
        <option value="Male & Child">Male & Child</option>
        <option value="Female & Child">Female & Child</option>
        <option value="Insured & Spouse">Insured & Spouse</option>
        <option value="Insured & Family">Insured & Family</option>
   </select><br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
<?php } // end not submitted?>`
```

Comment: change `'%$Categories%'` into `'$Categories'`. Because `%` is a wildcard and male is in feMALE.

Comment: okay, that awesome.  thank you very much, Gyan!

Answer (score 0):

try to change `<select name="Categories" />` to `<select name="Categories">` remove the backslash and remove the back tick at the end of script.